# static ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading

I have below 2 classes.  Different clients call the `TestThreadPool`, which in turn calls `TestThreadExecutor` to access `ExecutorService`.  So the problem is, `ThreadPool` is never kicked-off as it always creates a new `TestThreadExecutor`.

So, I would like to set `executeThreadExecutor` as static method to kick-off `threadPool`.  Is there any problem having static method and static `ExecutorService`?

Is there any other alternative way like singleton etc.?

---

```
public class Client {
  ...
  TestThreadPool testThreadPool = new TestThreadPool ();
  ...
}

public class TestThreadPool {
  public void executeThread() {
    TestThreadExecutor  test =  new TestThreadExecutor();
    ...
  }
}

public class TestThreadExecutor {
  public static ExecutorService testService = null;

  public static void executeThreadExecutor {
    if (testService == null) {      
      testService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);
    }
    ...
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You approach seems ok, and there is no problem with it, although I don't see any reason to make the `ExecutorService` public, since you are managing it through a method of the class, which is better for encapsulation. Of course, you can implement `TestThreadExecutor` as a singleton:

```
public class TestThreadExecutor {
   private ExecutorService testService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);
   private static TestThreadExecutor instance = new TestThreadExecutor();

   private TestThreadExecutor() {
   }

   public static TestThreadExecutor getInstance() {
       return instance;
   }        
}
```

Comment: why would you set the testService in the constructor?  why not just set it directly?  it's confusing to set static variables in a class constructor.

Comment: @jtahlborn: I agree, now that I think about it, it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful for me.  I would like to put executorService.shutdown().  Where should I have this?  Is it in catch block?  I tried putting it in finally, it is not accepting new tasks.

Comment: Well if you use `shutdown` you won't be able to add new tasks to the pool. `shutdown` will stop all pending tasks and not accept any new ones. It doesn't matter where you put it.

Comment: Thanks Tudor.  In case of exceptions, what will happen to the remaining tasks?

Comment: @user12121: A task is considered completed whether it finished normally or with an exception. The remaining tasks will execute without any problems.

Comment: So I can leave "static ExecutorService" as is? Without calling shutdown() forever? Would it cause a memory leak? I am coding in Android.

Comment: @jclova: I think that bit was wrong. `testService` should be an instance field of `TestThreadExecutor`, since you can't create new instances of `TestThreadExecutor ` anyway.